# Extend vuelidate with custom validators

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I am trying to extend Vuelidate object in my Vue app.
Currently I have following setup in my Vue Component.

```
import {required} from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

export default {
   validations: {
    ...
  }
}
```

I have created a new file custom-validator.js

```
import { helpers } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
export const OnlyDgitis = helpers.regex('onlyDigits', /^\d+$/);
```

I want to import `OnlyDgitis` along with predefined vuelidate validators from custom-validator.js

End Result

```
import {required, OnlyDgitis} from 'custom-validators.js'
```

What I have tried

```
import { helpers } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
   import * as Validators from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
   
   export const OnlyDgitis = helpers.regex('onlyDigits', /^\d+$/);
   export default Object.assign({}, Validators, {
     OnlyDgitis       
   });
```

Comment: try export like this   export const OnlyDigits; export const Validators = Validators;

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @EstusFlask please have a look at the end result in the question, I want to extend vuelidate predefined rules object with my custom rules.

Comment: I see. But I don't see what's the problem with it. Is there an error? Something works not as intended? The question lacks clear problem statement - technically there's no question. There likely should be `export * from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'`. Is this what you looked for?

Comment: @EstusFlask You are life saver. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following @EstusFlask suggestions from comments
Here's how finally got the desired results

```
// custom-validators.js

import { helpers } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

export const OnlyDgitis = helpers.regex('onlyDigits', /^\d+$/);

export * from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
```

Now I can easily import like so,

```
// My component.js
import {required, OnlyDgitis} from 'custom-validators.js'

export default {
   validations: {
    ...
  }
}
```